# Prettier extension in VS code breaks statement

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

when i try to save the code inside the for loop, the statement breaks into different lines.

am a newbie learning to code. I need the DOM code to be in single line statement. Appreciate help on this.

[image]

Comment: Better to call `document.querySelectorAll()` out of the loop any way and iterate through that node list : `let drumButtons = document.querySelectorAll(".drum"); for (var i = 0; i < drumButtons.length){ drumButtons[i].addEventListener("click", function(){}); }`

Answer (score 1):

Got it fixed. went to the Prettier extension settings and set the print width to 100 and this solved the problem of breaking the statement.

Thanks